# Net.HttpWebRequest difference between Powershell and PowerShell Core

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

Hoping someone can shed light on this. In Powershell, the following code generates output of the website certificate:

```
$req = [Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create('https://www.google.com')
$req.GetResponse()
$req.Servicepoint.certificate

       Handle Issuer                                       Subject
       ------ ------                                       -------
2266454817712 CN=GTS CA 1O1, O=Google Trust Services, C=US CN=www.google.com...
```

In Powershell Core, it returns a null/blank in `$req.Servicepoint.certificate`.

```
BindIPEndPointDelegate :
ConnectionLeaseTimeout : -1
Address                : https://www.google.com/
MaxIdleTime            : 100000
UseNagleAlgorithm      : True
ReceiveBufferSize      : -1
Expect100Continue      : True
IdleSince              : 20/09/2019 9:42:48 AM
ProtocolVersion        : 1.1
ConnectionName         : https
ConnectionLimit        : 2
CurrentConnections     : 0
Certificate            :
ClientCertificate      :
SupportsPipelining     : True
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like .NET Core [issue 36979](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/36979) explains this pretty well.

In short, [System.Net.HttpWebRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest) is obsolete and was only partially re-implemented in .NET Core. In particular, ServicePoint and ServicePointManager classes exist but don't really function.

They recommend migrating to [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) instead and one user offered the following code sample to demonstrate how to retrieve the certificate with it.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace NetCoreConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = CustomCallback;
            var client = new HttpClient(handler);

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("https://www.google.com.mx/").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine((int)response.StatusCode);
        }

        private static bool CustomCallback(HttpRequestMessage arg1, X509Certificate2 arg2, X509Chain arg3, SslPolicyErrors arg4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arg2.GetEffectiveDateString());
            Console.WriteLine(arg2.GetExpirationDateString());
            Console.WriteLine(arg2.Issuer);
            Console.WriteLine(arg2.Subject);

            return arg4 == SslPolicyErrors.None;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers Ryan, great pickup. I didn't find that on my initial research but it was sitting there plain as day.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody's interested, here's how I reworked that for PS Core:

```
$Req = [System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient]::new('www.google.com', '443')
$Stream = [System.Net.Security.SslStream]::new($Req.GetStream())
$Stream.AuthenticateAsClient('www.google.com')
$Stream.RemoteCertificate
$Stream.RemoteCertificate.GetExpirationDateString()
```

(etc)

[Ssl​Stream.​Remote​Certificate  Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.remotecertificate?view=netframework-4.8)